# How to correctly set redirect urls with Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, redirect, expo

I have an Expo application that is using AuthSession. I'm connecting my backend that does some stuff and afterwards should redirect to my app.

My issue is that this only works if I use the redirect url as `exp://blablabla`, which according to Expo's documentation, is wrong.

I should use something like `https://auth.expo.io/@username/project-slug`, but that just redirects to an empty page.

I have AuthSession set as

```
const url = Linking.makeUrl('/auth/success');
const result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
  authUrl: `https://my-back-end-url/auth/login`,
  returnUrl: url 
});
```

The `returnUrl` doesn't seem to be doing anything, really.

Furthermore if I use the `exp://blablabla` url to redirect, it will only work to the root of my project, which I don't really want.

What am I doing wrong here?

Cheers!